# How to use AND or OR with JPAContainer?

Tags: java, jpa, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm looking for how to use clauses AND or OR to do a login in my application. With SQL I use "SELECT * FROM person WHERE email = ? AND password = ?", but with JPAContainer I don't know how to do this.

```
//Beans
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull        
    @Size(min=5, max=50)
    private String name;

    @Email
    private Email email;

    @Size(min=8,max=8)
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    private PersonType personType;
}

@Entity
public class PersonType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull        
    @Size(min=5, max=50)
    private String personType;
}
```

How to I can check Email and Password of Person and return a List using JPAContainer ?

Comment: What sort of class is `Email`? Entity, embeddable, ... ? Also, why exactly do you want to use a JPAContainer to validate a login? Why don't you use a simple CriteriaQuery?

Comment: Or did you mean: `@Email private String email`?

Comment: @Email is a hibernate-validator annotation....I'm learning about CriteriaQuery.

Comment: Ok, so your `email` field is a `String`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you'd like to validate a login by checking both the `email` and the `password` fields. I'm not sure why you need a JPAContainer instead of a simple CriteriaQuery, but here's the answer to your question (off the top of my head):

```
JPAContainer<Person> container = 
     JPAContainerFactory.<Person>makeReadOnly(Person.class, entityManager);

container.addContainerFilter(new Compare.Equal("email", emailInput));
container.addContainerFilter(new Compare.Equal("password", passwordInput));

// Query container size, eg
if(container.size()==1) { ... }
```

If you add multiple container filters in this manner, they will implicitly be understood as the intersection thereof, ie. AND.

If you want the union of filter, ie. OR, you'll have to build it yourself as such (if that makes any sense is at your discretion):

```
Filter filter = new Compare.OR(new Compare.Equal("email", emailInput), new Compare.Equal("password", passwordInput));
container.addContainerFilter(filter);
```

However, I'll repeat that using *a plain CriteriaQuery may be more appropriate*.

---

Moreover —and don't take this lightly— from your `Person` entity, I infer that you're storing the passwords in clear in the database which is a big no-no, and

1. can put your users at risk if the database is compromised, and
2. could be a rough blow to your own reputation if your code is audited/reviewed.

---

**EDIT**:

With CriteriaQuery, you could something like:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> q = qb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Person> root = q.from(Person.class);
Path<String> email = root.get("email");
Path<String> password = root.get("password");

cq.select(cb.count(root)).where(
    cb.and(
        cb.equal(email, emailInput),
        cb.equal(password, passwordInput)
    )
);

return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
```

Replace `cb.and(...)` with `cb.or(...)` if you so wish. HTH.

Comment: How to use CriteriaQuery with container ?

Comment: See my edit above. You don't use it with the container though. What you want to do with your container is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do.

I did this.

```
EntityManager em = datasource.getEntityProvider().getEntityManager();       
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> c = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> person = c.from(Person.class);
c.where(
    cb.and(
cb.equal(person.get("email"), email.getValue()),
cb.equal(person.get("password"), password.getValue()))
);
TypedQuery tq = em.createQuery(c);
List<Person> lista = tq.getResultList();
```

And now works !